# Is CoreData migration proper in this scenario?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app that utilizes Core Data.  One of the Core Data entities is an NSInteger that represents an enumeration.  In my next revision, the enumeration values have changed and I need to remap the old enums to the new enums.

Is Core Data migration an appropriate approach in this case, as the model has not changed, just my interpretation of the data.  I've attempted to implement a migration policy, but I can't get it working (my migration policy never executes).

Thanks!

--John

Answer (score 0):

If you've added a couple of new values to the end of the enum, then I wouldn't migrate anything, just make sure the old numbers still equal the old values.

If you have changed the value that each enum represents, then you should not have used an enum in the first place as enums are never supposed to change. In this case I would add a new column or relationship and probably better not to use an enum this time.

Leave the old enum in the database structure, but have your subclass of NSManagedObject handle updating both values whenever either one changes (or something like that).